# Sending data to a list of ip addresses - c++

Tags: c++, networking, enet

Currently I am using [enet](http://enet.bespin.org/) to stream info, updated multiple times per second, to a list of
provided ip addresses / ports. I am creating a client connection for each of these
addresses (and there are server enet host connections running on those computers).

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to send these messages(or simply a better solution to the problem)? Some way that I do not have to create
a enet host for each connection? I do need reliable delivery.

I am only using enet as it is convenient and already available in the system I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great solution for this problem is [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/).

It is a networking library with C++ bindings that specializes in the reliable delivery of messages in a variety of configurations, like the pub/sub model that looks like what you are trying to do.

ZeroMQ would effectively allow you to not even need to list the IPs of the subscribers, since they would indeed subscribe by connecting to your publisher. The publisher then would send data regardless of the number of subscribers (see http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out).

Comment: Thanks for a great suggestion.  This might not work for me due to certain constraints (due to which I will now have to implement very similar functionality myself), but I will keep ZeroMQ in mind for the future.

Comment: @user1666594 may I ask you what kind of constraints you are talking about ?

Comment: The biggest problem with ZeroMQ is that it is not a neutral carrier .. which we need it to be